# Flink difference between view vs temporary table vs table

Tags: apache-flink

What is the difference between view vs temporary table vs table and it's usecases. Trying to understand when to use which?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read more on this topic at https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/common/#temporary-vs-permanent-tables

> Temporary tables are always stored in memory and only exist for the duration of the Flink session they are created within. These tables are not visible to other sessions. They are not bound to any catalog or database but can be created in the namespace of one. Temporary tables are not dropped if their corresponding database is removed.

> Tables can be either virtual (VIEWS) or regular (TABLES). VIEWS can be created from an existing Table object, usually the result of a Table API or SQL query. TABLES describe external data, such as a file, database table, or message queue.